# Reuse documentation from another namespace

Tags: jsdoc

I have a namespace that assigns the same function to the global namespace. 
For example

```js
/**
 * @namespace Main
 */
module.exports = {
  Sub: require('./sub')(module.exports),
  Sob: require('./sob')(module.exports)
  /* many other namespaces */
};
```

Then inside, for example, `sub.js`

```js
/**
 * @namespace Main.Sub
 */
module.exports = function(mainExports){
  return {
    /**
     * @function Main.Sub.addStuff 
     * // all the rest of documentation in here
     */
    addStuff: mainExports.addStuff = function(){
    }
  };
};
```

I want to be able to list the same function with the same params and everything on `Main` namespace. Right now, I'm duplicating the doc block, but changing the name of the `@function` tag to `@function Main.addStuff` and it works, but leads to a lot of noise in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, JSDoc doesn't provide a way to inherit another symbol's documentation.

For JSDoc 3.3.0 (the next major version), I plan to implement this feature by adding support for an `@inheritdoc` tag. This feature is tracked as [issue #53](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/53) in JSDoc's GitHub repo.